# How to recursively list subdirectories in Bash without using "find" or "ls" commands?

Tags: bash

I know you can use the `find` command for this simple job, but I got an assignment not to use `find` or `ls` and do the job. How can I do that?

Comment: What are you supposed to use to do this? Your own shell script, a C program, Java...? If you let us know what you *can* use, help should be more forthcoming :-)

Comment: You might be able to use `echo *` or variations on that to emulate `ls`.

Answer (score 39):

you can do it with just the shell

```
#!/bin/bash
recurse() {
 for i in "$1"/*;do
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
        echo "dir: $i"
        recurse "$i"
    elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
        echo "file: $i"
    fi
 done
}

recurse /path
```

OR if you have bash 4.0

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in /path/**
do
    echo $file
done
```

Comment: why don't you downvote the one with the tree command as well? or the one with echo, those are valid answers as well.

Comment: This will fail if a directory is empty, i.e. it will print `dir: bla/*` since `bla/*` is seen as a literal as it has no descendants. You can either use `pushd/popd`, or add `if [[ "$1/*" = "$i" ]]; then continue; fi` as the first line after `do`.

Comment: This could also be fixed (to not emit `bla/*`) by use of `shopt -s nullglob`, or `[ -e "$i" ] || [ -L "$i" ] || continue` inside the loop.

Answer (score 12):

Try using

```
tree -d
```

Comment: Why did I get a -1? Comment please.

Comment: I didn't give you the -1, but it's obvious to me why you got it.  Why not give as answer `alias bla ls ; bla`?  The question that was asked was to write the algorithm, not find some *command* which does the same thing as `ls` but is not called `ls`.

Comment: @Vlad Romascanu: Oh... ok, but from "I got an assignment not to use find or ls and do the job" I understood that everything was good enough, except find and ls ^^

Comment: On the other hand maybe his assignment has to run on Solaris or AIX or HPUX, not Linux. :)  Let me assure you there is no `tree` command available by default on non-Linuces etc.

Answer (score 5):

Below is one possible implementation:

```
# my_ls -- recursively list given directory's contents and subdirectories
# $1=directory whose contents to list
# $2=indentation when listing
my_ls() {
  # save current directory then cd to "$1"
  pushd "$1" >/dev/null
  # for each non-hidden (i.e. not starting with .) file/directory...
  for file in * ; do
    # print file/direcotry name if it really exists...
    test -e "$file" && echo "$2$file"
    # if directory, go down and list directory contents too
    test -d "$file" && my_ls "$file" "$2  "
  done
  # restore directory
  popd >/dev/null
}

# recursively list files in current
#  directory and subdirectories
my_ls .
```

As an exercise you can think of how to modify the above script to print full paths to files (instead of just indented file/dirnames), possibly getting rid of `pushd`/`popd` (and of the need for the second parameter `$2`) in the process.

Incidentally, note the use of `test XYZ && command` which is fully equivalent to `if test XYZ ; then command ; fi` (i.e. execute `command` if `test XYZ` is successful).  Also note that `test XYZ` is equivalent to `[ XYZ ]`, i.e. the above is also equivalent to `if [ XYZ ] ; then command ; fi`.  Also note that any semicolon `;` can be replaced with a newline, they are equivalent.

Remove the `test -e "$file" &&` condition (only leave the `echo`) and see what happens.

Remove the double-quotes around `"$file"` and see what happens when the directory whose contents you are listing contains filenames with spaces in them.  Add `set -x` at the top of the script (or invoke it as `sh -x scriptname.sh` instead) to turn on debug output and see what's happenning in detail (to redirect debug output to a file, run `sh -x scriptname.sh 2>debugoutput.txt`).

To also list hidden files (e.g. `.bashrc`):

```
...
for file in * .?* ; do
  if [ "$file" != ".." ] ; then
    test -e ...
    test -d ...
  fi
done
...
```

Note the use of `!=` (string comparison) instead of `-ne` (numeric comparison.)

Another technique would be to spawn subshells instead of using `pushd`/`popd`:

```
my_ls() {
  # everything in between roundbrackets runs in a separatly spawned sub-shell
  (
    # change directory in sub-shell; does not affect parent shell's cwd
    cd "$1"
    for file in ...
      ...
    done
  )
}
```

Note that on some shell implementations there is a hard limit (~4k) on the number of characters which can be passed as an argument to `for` (or to any builtin, or external command for that matter.)  Since the shell [expands, inline, `*` to a list of all matching filenames](http://www.bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/syntax/expansion/globs) before actually performing `for` on it, you can run into trouble if `*` is expanded inside a directory with a lot of files (same trouble you'll run into when running, say `ls *` in the same directory, e.g. get an error like `Command too long`.)

Comment: you can use `shopt -s dotglob` to list hidden files.

Comment: @ghostdog -- not portable.  `.*` (or `.?*` to skip `.` off the bat) does the trick just fine and is portable too.

Answer (score 5):

Since it is for bash, it is a surprise that this hasn't been already said:
(globstar valid from bash 4.0+)

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
echo **/*/
```

That's all.
The trailing slash `/` is there to select only dirs.

Option `globstar` activates the `**` (search recursivelly).
Option `nullglob` removes an `*` when it matches no file/dir.
Option `dotglob` includes files that start wit a dot (hidden files).

Answer (score 1):

The `du` command will list subdirectories recursively.

I'm not sure if *empty* directories get a mention, though

Answer (score 1):

Like Mark Byers said you can use `echo *` to get a list of all files in the current directory.

The `test` or `[]` command/builtin has an option to test if a file is a directory.

Apply recursion and you're done.

Comment: As an alternative to `echo`, `for` will glob, so OP can use `for file in * ; do ... ; done`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ function f { for i in $1/*; do if [ -d $i ]; then echo $i; f $i; fi; done }
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3 2/3 3
$ f .
./1
./1/2
./1/2/3
./2
./2/3
./3
```

Comment: -1 if you're going to provide a complete answer to a homework question, make it a correct one.  what about spaces in directory entry names?

Comment: and it does not enter directories and does not list text files

Comment: it DOES enter directories, and the OP said nothing about text files (or any files apart from directories).  I'm not going to fix the 'directories with spaces' issue.

Comment: Too bad. This was almost a great answer, but lacks the information I need (as a n00b) to tinker with it. Looks like just another string of bash-foo to me.

Comment: So you don’t like an answer written in bash to a question asking for bash because it’s too bashy? This may not be the site for you.

Comment: Not sure about bashy, but it's definitely *buggy*. Needs more quotes to correctly handle names with spaces. Less substantively, using ksh rather than POSIX function declaration syntax is [not great form](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the form I used is listed as correct on the page you listed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, neither [find](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) nor [ls](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/ls.html) are used by [find2perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html)|[perl](http://www.perl.org/) or [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) directly.

```
$ find2perl -type d | perl
$ perl -MFile::Find -e'find(sub{-d&&print"$File::Find::name\n"},".")'
```

Comment: but then, if that's the case, using Python/Ruby/PHP etc any language that can list files will be technically not using `ls` or `find`

Comment: @ghostdog74 Obviously.  But since all the serious answers have gotten less than amazing feedback, this is something... less serious.  (I was actually going to write up a clone of `find` in C and a shell script which compiles+runs it, but decided it was too much effort for a joke.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35502074/3266847); use [shell options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) for the desired globbing behaviour:

- enable `**` with `globstar` (Bash 4.0 or newer)
- include hidden directories with `dotglob`
- expand to the empty string instead of `**/*/` if there is no match with `nullglob`

and then use [`printf` with the `%q` formatting directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) to quote directory names with special characters in them:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob
printf '%q\n' **/*/
```

so if you have directories like `has space` or even containing a newline, you'd get output like

```
$ printf '%q\n' **/*/
$'has\nnewline/'
has\ space/
```

with one directory per line.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a another solution iterative instead of recursive.

```
iterativePrintDir() {    
    dirs -c;
    currentd=$1
    if [ ! -d $currentd ];then
            echo "Diretorio não encontrado. \"$currentd\""
    fi
    pushd $(readlink -f $currentd)

    while popd 2>&-; do
            echo $currentd
            for d in $(dir $currentd); do
                    test -d "${currentd}/${d}" && pushd  "${currentd}/${d}"
            done
            currentd=$(dirs -l +0)
    done
}
```