# bash : recursive listing of all files problem

Tags: bash

> Run a recursive listing of all the
>   files in   /var/log  and redirect
>   standard output to a file called
>   lsout.txt in your home directory. 
>   Complete this question WITHOUT leaving
>   your home directory.
>
> An: ls -R /var/log/ >
>   /home/bqiu/lsout.txt

**I reckon the above bash command is not correct. Because I found what it stores was :**

```
$ ls -R /var/log
/var/log:
empty.txt  setup.log  setup.log.full  tmp

/var/log/tmp:
fake.txt subfolder

/var/log/tmp/subfolder:
```

Does that mean problem resolved?

I reckon NOT.

Because it contains more "stuff" than "only files"

Or at least, if the purpose was to locate all "files" underneath the "/var/log" directory
recursively, then I hope to get the anwser like this:

```
/var/log/empty.txt  
/var/log/setup.log  
/var/log/setup.log.full
/var/log/tmp/fake.txt
```

So then someone can parse the content of the output for later use. Such like

```
$ perl -wnle 'print "$. :" , $_;' logfiles
1 :/var/log/empty.txt
2 :/var/log/setup.log
3 :/var/log/setup.log.full
4 :/var/log/tmp/fake.txt
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
$ ls -1R
.:
cal.sh
cokemachine.sh
dir
sort
test.sh

./dir:
afile.txt
file
subdir

./dir/subdir:

$ ls -R | sed s/^.*://g

cal.sh
cokemachine.sh
dir
sort
test.sh


afile.txt
file
subdir
```

But this still leaves all directory/sub-directory names (dir and subdir), plus a couple of empty newlines

**How could I get the correct result without using Perl or awk?** Preferably using only basic bash commands(this is just because Perl and awk is out of assessment scope)

**Edited : I focused on my own "$HOME" folder just to restrict the file listed. I am having little content in my homedir**

**Edited 2nd: Sorry about my inapproprated question in the initial form. I fixed the wording and hopefully everyone can see the problem now.**

Comment: The question is not clear -- what *is* correct? Should each line of the final output be of form `./dir/afile.txt`? Basenames only?

Comment: Have you tried the `find` command?

Comment: The main obvious thing wrong with the provided answer is that the output file should be '$HOME/lsout.txt'; most people's HOME is not in /home/bqiu.  The main thing wrong with what you are doing seems to be that you are ignoring the request to list the contents of /var/log.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : I thought just play around with my home dir would be safer and better to illustrate the problem

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154166/how-to-recursively-list-subdirectories-in-bash-without-using-find-or-ls-commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try -

find /var/log > ~/lsout.txt

Comment: Don't think this is what was meant.  Plus, how can you guarantee that your `find` implementation does not leave the home directory?

Comment: @Vlad: I'd let the op decide what pipit was desired. As for the find command "leaving. The home directory-- I have no idea what you're talking about. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

**If you were given no restrictions** in terms of which commands can or cannot be used, `ls -R /var/log >~/lsout.txt` or `find /var/log -print >"$HOME/lsout.txt"` or any similar combination will work just fine.

However, **if the point of the assignment is to write a 100% `sh`-based implementation**, without using `ls -R`, `find`, etc. then you should be producing something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Helper method which recursively lists the contents of a given directory
# Usage: recurse_ls target_directory
recurse_ls()
{
  TARGET_DIR="$1"
  # list contents of $TARGET_DIR
  ...
  # - recursive call to list contents of sub-directories
  recurse_ls ...
  ...
}



# MAIN
# Usage: script.sh target_directory
# - check that parameters to script.sh are correct
...
# - list the contents of target_dir and its subdirectories
recurse_ls "$1"
```

Useful links:

- [variable expansion and parameter substitution](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/parameter-substitution.html)
- [file type test operations](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/fto.html)
- [globbing (wildcard expansion)](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/globbingref.html)
- [quoting to account for blanks in variable values (including filenames)](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/quoting.html)

Comment: @Vlad Romascanu :
Thanks for this sample skeleton code. This question is left "unfinished" as taken from a collection of multiple choice questions, I reckon. I just felt the "proposed" answer in the past was not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the answer they want is:
`ls -R /var/log/ > /home/bqiu/lsout.txt`
ie. the original answer you said was wrong.

Except you may want to write it as:
`ls -R /var/log/ > ~/lsout.txt`. 
That way it outputs to the home directory of whoever is logged in, rather than just user "bqiu".

When it says: `Run a recursive listing of all the files`
To me `ls` stands for `listing` and the `-R` option stands for `recursive`.
So to me the wording of the question suggests using `ls -R` to produce the listing,

But a it depends upon what format they want the listing.