# Bash - What is a good way to recursively find the type of all files in a directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, file, recursion

I am not too deep in the material and rarely use Bash scripts.
Even with some research, I couldn't quickly learn everything in Bash so that I could search an entire directory with its sub-directories for files and then output their type. I've now gotten a bit into the direction of functions, but again don't quite know how to do this recursively. Also, I want to consider only files and not folders.
Here is something I have already done on my own:

```
for item in "$1"/*
do
    if ! [ -d $item ]; then
        echo $(file $item)
    fi
done;
```

So when the script is called, the path is passed as an argument. The path is then searched for non-directories and their type is output with the command file.
But how is this recursive and also implementable for sub-directories?
I have also tried it by iterating over ls -R, but then names of folders are still appended and I can no longer check via my way if it is a folder or a file.
Edit: I can't use find!

I am glad about any help!

Comment: try this `find . -type f -exec file {} +`

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to write that. I can not use find :/

Comment: Huh! What version of bash are targeting? bash-4+?

Comment: It's not necessarily about that, but rather about learning and practicing. With find it would be just a one-liner, yes

Comment: `find` is definitely the best way to do this. Just use `find`. Using recursive glob expansion on a large directory tree (`file **`) could exceed the system's `ARG_MAX` when passing all those files to `file`. `find` handles this for you. You could use `xargs` to manage it but I can't see a good reason to, except maybe to run parallel `file` processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:  [How to recursively list subdirectories in Bash without using "find" or "ls" commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154166/how-to-recursively-list-subdirectories-in-bash-without-using-find-or-ls-comm)

That said, I modified it to accept user input as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

recurse() {
 for i in "$1"/*;do
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
        echo "dir: $i"
        recurse "$i"
    elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
        echo "file: $i"
    fi
 done
}

recurse $1
```

If you didn't want the files portion (which it appears you don't) then just remove the elif and line below it. I left it in as the original post had it also.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have the following problem:
`if ! [ -d "$i" ]; then
    echo $(file §i)
else
    recurse "$i"'
My output is 3x directory, which isn't true and I need files, nit directories :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash extended globbing capabilities:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob globstar
$ for i in **/*; do [ -d "$i" ] && continue; file "$i"; done
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the solution suggestion.
With a small optimization of the path specification in for it works, but I am confused. Now where is globstar used and is this really recursive? I don't see a self call

Comment: `globstar` is Bash option, read about it in `man bash`. What's _self call_?

Comment: You can get more useful help using `help set` and `help shopt`, by the way.

Comment: Thanks! Recursion describes that a function calls itself again in order to reach the desired goal

Comment: Somewhat simplified: `for i in **/*; do [ ! -d "$i" ] && file "$i"; done`

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggesting

```
   file $(find -type f 2>/dev/null)
```

#### Explanation:

1. `find` command that search recursively into current folder.
2. Filter only files from `find` command: `-type f` .
3. Ignore any `find` permission/access errors with `2>/dev/null`
4. Run `file` command on each found file.